# Joomla 1.5 to 2.5 - how to get group names of component settings

Tags: joomla, settings, upgrade

I am upgrading a Joomla Website from 1.5 to 2.5 and I have a problem with a custom component which gets the setting params from the **JEvents** component. The old source tries to get the group names of these settings like this:

```
$groups = $this->params->getGroups();
```

But this does not work with Joomla 2.5.

I didn't find useful information on Google, so maybe you can help me out with this.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If it's simply the parameters from JEvents that you want to retrieve, then you can use the following:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$params = $app->getParams('com_events');

$var1 = $params->get('paramName1');
$var2 = $params->get('paramName2');
$var3 = $params->get('paramName3');
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Sadly not. This is close, but I need the group names of JEvents config. Group names are like the tabs where the params are in.
Thank you very much.

Comment: @user2665142 - ahh I see. I'll try and come up with something when I get back.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort @Lodder

Comment: Nothing new for this issue? =(

Comment: @user2665142 - unfortunately I haven't been able to come up with anything :/

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by myself.

I changed the component input to a Form instead of Parameters and bound the Parameter Data in a JRegistry to the form.

The view works with fieldsets as groups.